# C# Получить объект вызвавший getter свойства

Tags: c#, wpf

Здравствуйте!
У меня возникла проблема "красивого" способа изменения настроек "на лету".
 
Наример:

```
private string _text;
public string SampleTextProp
{
    get
    {
        return _text;
    }

    set
    {
        _text = value;
    }
}

textBlock1.Text = SampleTextProp;
```

И вопрос:
Есть ли возможность внутри геттера `SampleTextProp` получить объект `textBlock1.Text`, чтобы позже использовать его? В сеттере например.
То есть мне нужно получить объект, который вызвал геттер.
Надеюсь я понятно выразился...

Спасибо большое!


**Update**: Для чего мне это нужно.
Есть класс хранящий в себе настройки для приложения представленные как свойства. По мере написания программы я применяю эти свойства к различным полям или свойствам других объектов. Но эти настройки будут применяться только при запуске программы, а мне надо видеть изменения во время исполнения. В тоже время я не хочу вручную связывать настройку и объект применяющий её (`windowBorder.BorderThickness = Settings.Interface.BorderThickness.GetValue(windowBorder)` или как-то так) 
Я хотел чтобы можно было просто вызвать свойство и всё. А класс его описывающий самостоятельно получил бы вызывающий объект, запомнил, и при последующем изменении свойства, автоматически применил новое значение ко всем ранее вызывавшим это свойство объектам. Фух

Comment: +1 за кавычки вокруг слова *красивого*

Comment: _Есть ли возможность внутри геттера SampleTextProp получить объект textBlock1.Text, чтобы позже использовать его?_ - нет

Comment: @Grundy, грустно

Comment: @IvanCherkasov, А Вам нужна именно ссылка на объект или какая то другая информация?

Comment: А почему грустно? Если вам хочется того, чего нет в языке, возможно, у вас просто неправильный подход к проблеме. _Зачем _ вам в функции (а геттер — это просто функция же) знать, кто именно вызвал функцию? Что вы можете сделать полезного с этой информацией?

Comment: @VladD, я дополнил вопрос описанием

Comment: @AntonKomyshan, именно ссылка на объект

Comment: Вы используете WinForms или WPF?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, WPF

Answer (score 4, accepted):

То, что вам нужно, называется "дата-биндинг" (data binding, по русски - привязка данных) и идет рука об руку с шаблоном проектирования MVVM (Model - View - View Model).

Для WinForms это делается через вкладку свойств, далее - пункт (ApplicationSettings) для привязки настроек или пункт (DataBindings) для привязки источника данных.

В WPF это делается через указание в разметке конструкции `{Binding}`:

```
BorderThickness="{Binding BorderThickness, Source={x:Static Settings.Default}}"
```

Если вы используете не стандартный класс настроек, а пишите свой - не забудьте реализовать интерфейс [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Спасибо! Выглядит многообещающе) Буду пробовать

Answer (score 0):

Нет. Никак нельзя.

При присвоении значения в любую пропертю ты передаешь ЛИШЬ значение проперти.

Но ты можешь написать метод который бы сразу обьект и из него доставал бы текст,если для тебя это важно.